# Multiplying a number with pi value in python

Tags: python, input, types

I wish to accept a number in float from the user and give back an answer multiplying that number with pi value = 3.14

heres my code:

```
print "Enter a no."
n = raw_input('enter here: ')
result = 1
def gen_pi(x):
    result = x*3.14
    return float(result)

gen_pi(n)
```

its giving me an error of not being able to multiply non int sequence with float. what does it mean? anything wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0):

The result of `raw_input` is a `str` which means that `n` is a `str` and then in your function, `x` is a `str` which can't multiply a `float`.

you'll want to convert `x` into a float before multiplying by `pi`.

There are lots of places to do this, but I'd recommend doing it before passing to `gen_pi`:

```
gen_pi(float(n))
```

This way, `gen_pi` can always assume it's working with a `float` and that code can be simplified:

```
def gen_pi(x):
    return x * 3.14
```

Also note that if you want *more* precision (and possibly a bit more code clarity), you can use `math.pi`:

```
import math
def gen_pi(x):
    return x * math.pi
```

Comment: And then additionally, since `3.14` is already a float, `result` (in `gen_pi`) will also be a float. So `return float(result)` should be just `return result`.

Comment: @aneroid -- Right.  I was apparently writing that up as you were commenting.